# Getting XY Coordinates/Lat Lon from OSMNX Consolidate Intersections

Tags: osmnx

With reference to [OSMnx Get Lat Lon Coordinates of Clean Intersection Nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50913798/osmnx-get-lat-lon-coordinates-of-clean-intersection-nodes)
and the recent change from clean_intersections to consolidate_intersections, the snippets in the original link do not appear to work.how can we get the same XY coorindates and Lat Lon now with consoilidate_intersections?

Answer (score 0):

This will vary if you provide `rebuild_graph=True` vs `False` as the `consolidate_intersections` parameterization. See [the docs](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.simplification.consolidate_intersections). I'll assume you mean the default parameterization. Just dump your graph to a GeoDataFrame then x, y, lat, and lon will be in the columns:

```py
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)
G = ox.graph_from_place('Piedmont, CA, USA', network_type='drive')
Gc = ox.consolidate_intersections(ox.project_graph(G))
nodes = ox.graph_to_gdfs(Gc, edges=False)
nodes[['x', 'y', 'lat', 'lon']]
```